# Как перенаправить в root_url при передаче в ActionCable: event: render_event(@event)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  ...
def new
    @event = Event.new
end
def create
@event = Event.new(event_params) 
if @event.save
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel_user_#{user.id}",
                               event: render_event(@event)
  else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private 

    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:user_id, :performance, :name, :tip_event, :description, :priority,
                                   :subcategory_id, :category_id)
    end

    def render_event(event)
      render(partial: 'event', locals: { event: event })
    end
...
end
```

При вызове ActionCable срабатывает рендер(render_event), а мне нужно чтобы после create страница показывала все event(т.е. мне нужно root_url вместо "/events").

Как совершить перенаправление?

Comment: Как выглядит метод `render_event`? И что будет, если в create добавить `redirect_to root_path` в конце?

Comment: Ошибка double render, метод: render(partial: 'event', locals: { event: event })

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос весь код экшна контроллера и код метода `render_event`

Comment: Изменения внесены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен [`render_to_string`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string). Он делает то же самое, но не устанавливает `response.body`, поэтому может быть использован вместе с другим рендерингом или редиректом.

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params) 
  if @event.save
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel_user_#{user.id}",
                                 event: render_event(@event)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def render_event(event)
  render_to_string(partial: 'event', locals: { event: event })
end
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Comment: @9karamba всегда пожалуйста :)